# Getting date range based on date and hour

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, utc

I am trying to get individual dates ("2022-10-10") and hours ("2022-10-10T09") between an interval in UTC. I could get the individual dates by the following -

```js
function getDatesInRange(startDate, endDate) {
    const date = new Date(startDate.getTime());

    const dates = [];

    while (date <= endDate) {
        const day = new Date(date).toISOString().split(':')[0].split('T')[0];
        dates.push(day);

        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    }
    return dates;
}
console.log(getDatesInRange(new Date('2022-10-10T20:50:59.938Z'), new Date('2022-10-15T23:50:59.938Z')));
```

Hence, the above returns - `["2022-10-10", "2022-10-11", "2022-10-12", "2022-10-13", "2022-10-14", "2022-10-15"]`

I also want to return the hours of the start and end date and the rest should be dates. So i want to get in return - `["2022-10-10T20", "2022-10-10T21", "2022-10-10T22", "2022-10-10T23" "2022-10-11", "2022-10-12", "2022-10-13", "2022-10-14", "2022-10-15T00", "2022-10-15T01"]`

Here is what i have as of now -

```js
function getHoursInRange(startDate, endDate) {
  let startDatePlusOne = new Date(startDate);
  startDatePlusOne.setDate(startDatePlusOne.getDate() + 1);
  
  let endDateMinusOne = new Date(endDate);
  endDateMinusOne.setDate(endDateMinusOne.getDate() - 1);
  
  const date = new Date(startDate.getTime());
  
  console.log("Start date :", date);
  let dates = getDatesInRange(startDatePlusOne, endDateMinusOne);
  console.log("Only days : ", dates);
  
  startDatePlusOne.setHours(0);

    while (date < startDatePlusOne) {
        const day = new Date(date).toISOString().split(':')[0];
        dates.push(day);

        date.setHours(date.getHours() + 1);
    }
    endDateMinusOne.setHours(23);
    const edate = endDateMinusOne.getTime();
    while (edate < endDate) {
        const day = new Date(edate).toISOString().split(':')[0];
        dates.push(day);

        date.setHours(date.getHours() + 1);
    }
  return dates
}
```

For this use case, i am getting the days back excluding the start and end dates. But for getting each hour of start and end date it gets stuck somehow. Somehow i feel there is a better way to do this. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it a simpler way by incrementing the timestamp by 30 minutes at a time, and keeping a note of all non-duplicate hour strings and date strings:

```js
function getDatesInRange(startDate, endDate) {
  let h = new Set(), d = new Set(), t = [];
  for(let i=startDate.getTime(); i<endDate.getTime(); i+=1000*1800) t.push(i);
  [...t, endDate.getTime()].forEach(i=>{
    let s = new Date(i).toISOString();
    [[s.split(':')[0], h], [s.split('T')[0], d]].forEach(([s,r])=>r.add(s));
  });
  let firstDate = [...d.values()][0], lastDate = [...d.values()].pop();
  return d.size===1 ? [...h.values()] : [
    ...[...h.values()].filter(v=>v.startsWith(firstDate)),
    ...[...d.values()].filter(v=>v!==firstDate && v!==lastDate),
    ...[...h.values()].filter(v=>v.startsWith(lastDate))];
}
console.log(getDatesInRange(
  new Date('2022-10-10T20:50:59.938Z'), new Date('2022-10-15T23:50:59.938Z')));
```

Answer (score 0):

`dateRange` constructs an array of `Date` objects corresponding to the supplied range, inclusive.

`dayToString` takes a date and creates an array of strings, one for each hour of the day between the specified UTC hour range, inclusive.

`dateRangeToStrings` accepts an array of dates and constructs an array of strings according to the rules laid-out in the question.

```js
const twoDigit = (n) => String(n).padStart(2, '0')
const toISODateString = (date) => `${date.getUTCFullYear()}-${twoDigit(date.getUTCMonth() + 1)}-${twoDigit(date.getUTCDate())}`
    
const dateRange = (start, end, curr = new Date(start)) => {
    const dates = []
    while (curr <= end) {
        dates.push(new Date(Date.UTC(curr.getUTCFullYear(), curr.getUTCMonth(), curr.getUTCDate())))
        curr.setUTCDate(curr.getUTCDate() + 1)
    }
    return dates
}

const dayToString = (date, startUTCHour = 0, endUTCHour = 23) =>
    Object.keys([...Array(24)])
          .slice(startUTCHour, endUTCHour + 1)
          .map((h)=>`${toISODateString(date)}T${twoDigit(h)}`)

const dateRangeToStrings = (arr, startUTCHour, endUTCHour) => {
    const beginning = dayToString(arr[0], startUTCHour)
    const middle = arr.slice(1, -1).map(toISODateString)
    const end = dayToString(arr[arr.length - 1], 0, endUTCHour)
    return beginning.concat(middle, end)
}

const getDatesInRange = (start, end) => 
    dateRangeToStrings(dateRange(start, end), 
                      start.getUTCHours(), 
                      end.getUTCHours())

console.log(getDatesInRange(new Date('2022-10-10T20:50:59.938Z'), 
                            new Date('2022-10-15T23:50:59.938Z')))
```